# Ubuntu 14.04 stops responding and capslock light blinks

Tags: 14.04

So, I have a HP pavilion 15 notebook. I have dual boot it with factory installed windows 8.1 and ubuntu 14.04. It is working well. But sometimes, it stops responding. Screen freezes as it is and caps lock starts blinking.
Then it don't respond again.I have to restart the laptop manually by power button to access again.
What is the reason for this?
What is its solution?

This never happened in windows?
And Its HDD haven't any errors...

Comment: If I remember properly (we had a bonfire with our pavilion) the blinking LED's indicate a hardware problem.  Look into HP's website using your model number, and track down the user manual appropriate to your computer.  [This link](http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=emr_na-c01732674) may help

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a hardware failure issue

Comment: Does it still react on the magic ALT+SYSRQ combinations? Hold those two keys and then additionally hit the keys "R", "E", "I", "S", "U", "B" in this order, one after the other, leaving about 10-20 seconds between each keystroke.

Comment: @Charles Green, It is not hardware issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*A blinking Caps Lock LED* indicates that a **kernel panic** jut happened.

[Why does my 'Caps Lock' diode blink when my system freezes?](https://askubuntu.com/q/265996/350004)