# Kernel panic in new laptop. Is it easy to fix or better exchange the device?

Tags: kernel, graphics, amd-graphics, inspiron

Yesterday got my new Inspiron 5567. Sometimes it freezes and Caps Lock starts to blink. I read that it means kernel panic. 
Is this issue big enough to go to the guarantee service? Also a small question - can kernel panic be related to the graphics card performance? This is quite poor, unfortunately...

Comment: Caps lock blinking is a hardware signal, and it usually means a CPU or memory failure. Where'd you hear it meant a kernel panic?

Comment: @Zacharee1 Caps lock blinks on mine in a kernel panic. [See here](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/drivers/input/serio/i8042.c?id=refs/tags/v3.9-rc1#n1031).

Comment: @Zacharee1 I read it in maaany places (e.g., https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2130905, http://askubuntu.com/questions/265996/why-does-my-caps-lock-diode-blink-when-my-system-freezes, http://askubuntu.com/questions/702461/ubuntu-14-04-stops-responding-and-capslock-light-blinks).
Also the symptom of complete freeze (such that I am even unable to reboot the laptop or call terminal, thus can only turn the device off) looks like something very much of kernel panic too.

Comment: If exchange is possible, I say do it.