# Facing annoying problem with Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04

I have been facing an annoying problem on Ubuntu 16.04. My system freezes and caps lock keep blinking until I shut down forcefully.
Both things happening simultaneously, worst part is nothing works out when it freezes. I updated grub by using */etc/default/grub*.

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash intel_idle.max_cstate=1"
```

but nothing happened. I tried a variety of keyboard combinations (found on the internet, like <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>SysRq</kbd>+<kbd>REISUB</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, and others), but none actually worked. I have changed my system motherboard but still facing the same issue. What should I do?

I have attached system log report:

[image: system log report]

Comment: Hi, did you run `sudo update-grub` after editing of `/etc/default/grub`?

Comment: Yeah, i did it but nothing happened.

Comment: "The freeze" may have many possible causes: Bad RAM, dying HDD, video card running a poorly-chosen driver, corrupted kernel, etc. Channel your inner Sherlock Holmes - you must methodically eliminate each possible cause. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/265996/why-does-my-caps-lock-diode-blink-when-my-system-freezes for the CAPS LOCK blinking (it's simply saying that you had a freeze).

Comment: I have checked Ram, HDD even changed the entire mother board nothing happened.

Comment: I checked above link couldn't get it what i have to do. can you please elaborate.  Any help highly appreciate.